# Maximize a function including Gamma function

Tags: optimization

I have the following optimization problem:
$$\max_{x}~\frac{A^{x}}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)}$$
such that $A > 0$ and $x \in (0,1)$. How can we obtain the optimal $x$?

**My attempt**: I wrote $\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x) = \frac{\pi x}{\sin(\pi x)}$ and equate the first derivative of $\frac{A^{x}}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)}$ with respect to $x$ to $0$. I got the following:
$$\frac{A^x \log(A)\sin(\pi x)}{(\pi x)}+ \frac{A^x \cos(\pi x)}{x}-\frac{A^x \sin(\pi x)}{(\pi x^2)} = 0. \tag1$$
I could not find the optimal $x$ from ($1$).

Answer (score 0):

You have done a mistake; it should be $\max_x A^x \frac{sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ what you wanted to differentiale and equate to 0.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question. Still I cannot simplify (1) to obtain the solution.

Comment: You can try to find a solution by setting x as a solution of $cos(\pi x) = 0$. Then solve for the integer $n$.

Comment: This will give the solution $x = 1/2$ as $x \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Such an equation I would solve numerically or by using a function plot tool (I think there will be free online plotters) for the general case.

Comment: Yes. I did that already. I am more interested in an analytical solution if there is any.